# Python timing code incorrect when calling parallel module - my code or the module?

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have some code that runs a mathematical simulation, and times it.

When I run this code without multithreading, the timing code works perfectly fine.

When I run the code *with* multithreading; the time is unreasonably small - using a watch, I reckon it's about 4-8 times *faster* than the time it takes the actual code to run. (code takes approx 12s to run, the `time` module says 1.5-2.5s)

Simplified code: (control flow explained in slightly more detail below)

```
class GenX:

    def log_results(self, solver):

            time2 = time.clock()
            print '%0.3f' % time2 - self.time1
            ^
            ##### this value is incorrect ###########

    def __init__(self):
        self.time1 = time.clock()

        mySimulation.setup()
        mySimulation.OnceCompleteCall(log_results)

        ## (in reality both setup and start are more complicated)

    def optimize(self):
        mySimulation.start()
        return
```

I have another class that instantiates this GenX class, then runs GenX.optimize(), starting the simulation.

The simulation is a separate module that handles the threading code internally (it's also a 1000 line class of which about 50% is unnecessary getters/setters... so I think the author may well be the source of the problem)

Once the simulation is finished, it calls log_results, which calculates the time taken - which is incorrect.

Currently I have no idea whether the source of the bug is my code or the module I am using.

I have checked that the author of the module calls `pool.join()` on completing the parallel operations - it does get called but the timing is still incorrect.

Comment: Do you [`join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) to the worker threads to block until they are complete?

Comment: Yes - that function does get called by the module that handles the multiprocessing code. I've updated the question.

Comment: Did you try to print all places there self.time1 changes? Also I recommend you to create a decorator @timer, and check how much time you spend on every step.

Comment: For every run of the program, self.time1 is only assigned to once - the stage seen in code above. It's not modified anywhere else.


I am personally not familiar with decorators yet, and the timing code isn't critical, so I've approximated it by simply empirically determing that it's about a factor of 5 out and just multiplying it, which should do for now... Although it is somewhat hacky!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how many threads you have, how many threads your CPU processes at a time, and what the threads are doing, I would assume that this is related to the following issue: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/26669. It could be that as clock is just measuring the processing time instead of wall time, the value you get is lower than what you expect.

Try to use time.time() instead.